# VBS call CMD with Quote in Argument

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I am trying to pass a snipit of code as a command line argument to a program running on WinXP.
I have not been able to pass the entire code snipit as one argument.
It gets split by SPACE and QUOTE characters (as expected).
Quoting the whole thing and escaping QUOTE chars with QUOTE, SLASH or CARAT also fails...

```
Const TheCode = "main(""Literal String Argument"", 123, true)"
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run """c:\Folder with space\ArgTest.vbs"" """ & TheCode & """"
```

I run the following vbs script to echo the arguments back to test what is recieved.

ArgTest.vbs:

```
Dim ArgumentIndex
For ArgumentIndex = 0 to Wscript.Arguments.Count - 1
    Call Msgbox(Wscript.Arguments(ArgumentIndex), vbOKOnly+vbInformation, "Argument " & ArgumentIndex)
Next
```

Edit:
It turns out that it is the VBS Echo script that stips out the QUOTES. Use QUOTE to escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard in Windows for escaping quotes. It is entirely up to the discretion of the developer of the app how quotes should be escaped. If you don't have documentation for your app that explains how to do it, then you will have to discover it on your own (assuming the app even supports escaped quotes)

It sounds like you tried back slash:

```
Const TheCode = "main(\""Literal String Argument\"", 123, true)"
```

You also say you tried caret:

```
Const TheCode = "main(^""Literal String Argument^"", 123, true)"
```

Have you tried doubling up the quotes?

```
Const TheCode = "main(""""Literal String Argument"""", 123, true)"
```

Comment: I was testing with a second vbs script (see edited post). I just tried writing a simple exe to echo the args. Whe I run it with that, the double quotes work. I guess vbs strips the quotes out of to args passed to it. Thanks